# How to enhance Yii1 application with Yii2 restfull api?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

Have a running Yii1 application. How to enhance Yii1 application with Yii2 restfull api instead of rewriting the whole Yii1 application in Yii 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can work with two separate application or with a yii2 and yii1 application integrated .   [see this doc for details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html).

Essentially you must install Yii 2 in your existing application and modify the entry script of the application as indicated in the doc ,
Because both Yii 1 and Yii 2 have the Yii class, you should create a customized version to combine them.

Once you have your yii2 application you can call the services you need 
here you can find a [quick start guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) for restful webservices in yii2

Comment: After integration, correct steps to use only yii2 Restfull in yii1?  Create Yii2 app/common and app/rest. Gii generate relevant models. For REST will be used Yii2, everything else will remain on Yii1. In Yii2 even do not need anything complex: 1.Gii model POST 2. Create a simple controller Rest for the model "post" is ready. Available on https://your-url-server.local/rest/web/index.php?r=posts (GET POST PUT DELETE)

Comment: Need to merge yii1 and yii2 model or yii1 will understand yii2 model?